# What determines if a variable is closed over?

Tags: c#

```
//var sample= new { bottom=2, top=5,count=4};
var sample= new [] {2,3,4,5,6};
var q = from x in new int[]{0} //force desired behavior
    from i in sample
    from j in sample
    select Math.Pow(i,j);


q.Distinct().Count().Dump();
sample = new[]{2,3,4,5};
//q = from i in Enumerable.Range(sample.bottom, sample.top-sample.bottom+1)
//  from j in Enumerable.Range(sample.bottom, sample.top-sample.bottom+1)
//  select checked(System.Numerics.BigInteger.Pow((BigInteger)i,j));
q.Distinct().Count().Dump();
```

2nd answer is incorrect every time if the `from x line` is not there, or the resetting of the `q` variable is not done.(shown here commented out)

Original sample was an anonymous variable, but the array did it also.

`var sample = new { bottom =2, top=5};`

Is it related to this [Scope of Linq Expressions defined in a loop - At issue: closing over loop variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154125/scope-of-linq-expressions-defined-in-a-loop-at-issue-closing-over-loop-variab) ?

Why did putting a 1 item array on the top fix the closure?

Comment: You problem had to do with lazy evaluation not closure.

Comment: can't it be both? in a sense it is the lazy evaluation wherein one part is being eagerly evaluated, the other lazily. which to me is one closing and one not.

Comment: This seems to agree with both of us. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step to understanding what is going on here is to understand how a query expression is translated. Per the specification:

```
from x1 in e1
from x2 in e2
select v
```

is translated into

```
e1.SelectMany(x1 => e2, (x1, x2) => v)
```

This is *incredibly* important to understand. The result of `from x1 in e1 from x2 in e2 select v` **is a query on e1**, whatever `e1` is; it is *fixed*, period.

Now, here's the issue. Let's look at your query.

```
var q = from i in sample
        from j in sample
        select Math.Pow(i, j)
```

The value of `sample` at at the time the query is constructed is a reference to the result of the array-creation expression `new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }`. Let `e1` be a reference to the result of that array-creation expression. Then the query becomes:

```
e1.SelectMany(i => sample, (i, j) => Math.Pow(i, j));
```

This is *fixed*, period, no matter what you reassign to `sample`. That is, you *have* to think of

```
var sample = new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
var q = from i in sample
        from j in sample
        select Math.Pow(i, j)
```

as

```
var sample = new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var e1 = sample;
var q = e1.SelectMany(i => sample, (i, j) => Math.Pow(i, j));
```

Now, `sample` *is* closed over, and that's why *after* you assign a new value to `sample`, you see a different query result. But **no matter what**, `e1` stays fixed as the result of the array-creation expression `new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }`.

However, when you start with the query

```
var q = from x in new int[] { 0 }
        from i in sample
        from j in sample
        select Math.Pow(i, j)
```

*now* the query is translated to

```
int[] e1 = new int[] { 0 };
var q = e1.SelectMany(
    x1 => sample.SelectMany(i => sample, (i, j) => Math.Pow(i, j)
);
```

and *now* `sample` is captured as the sequence for both `i` *and* `j` but `e1` is fixed.

Comment: +1 Your translation of the first query in OP's question might be more accurate than mine.

Comment: Is there a way to write this such that the entire query is closed over properly without introducing a fake 1 item array but it still works as desired?

Answer (score 2):

This code closes over `sample` twice.

```
from x in new int[]{0}
from i in sample
from j in sample
select Math.Pow(i,j);
```

The actual method calls this evaluates to are:

```
new int[] {0}
    .SelectMany(x => sample, (x, i) => new {x, i})
    .SelectMany(@t => sample, (@t, j) => Math.Pow(@t.i, j));
```

This code closes over `sample` once.

```
from i in sample
from j in sample
select Math.Pow(i,j);
```

The actual method calls this evaluates to are:

```
sample.SelectMany(i => sample, (i, j) => Math.Pow(i, j));
```

So if you change `sample`, only the `i => sample` lambda will "see" the "new" value for `sample`; `sample.SelectMany` has already run with the "old" value.

Both examples cause R# to issue an *Access to modified closure* warning, which is usually a big red flag. Consider keeping a private copy of `sample` for each of your queries, or have a function parameter do it for you:

```
IEnumerable<int> SelectManyPow(int[] sample)
{
    return from i in sample
           from j in sample
           select Math.Pow(i, j);
}
```